# doubly linked list - garbage collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

I have created a doubly linked list. My list contains only 2 elements (suppose `node1` and `node2`)  and  I want to delete the `head` pointer which points to the first node (`node1`) in the list. Because in Cpython the primary algorithm for garbage collection is reference counting.

Now my question is -(**Example-1**) if I set the `self.head`  to `self.head = self.head.next` and set `node2` `prev` (previous) attribute to `None` -  does this  delete the first node completly from  the memory? Because the `node1` has now no other references.  Or do have to call `del` method as shown in the second example **(Example-2)**? Which is the right way to delete the `node1` completly from the meomory?

**Example-1:**

```
def remHead(self):
  temp=self.head.next
  self.head=self.head.next
  temp.prev=None
```

**Example-2:**

```
def remHead(self):
  temp=self.head.next
  del self.head
  self.head=temp
  self.head.prev=None
```

Answer (score 2):

By `del self.head`, you delete the reference to the node, not the node itself. By re-assigning, the reference to the node is lost. Normally, in both ways, there is nothing left pointing to the next node. In general, Python deletes something from memory as soon as there are no references to it. So, in your case both have the same result. I would prefer just reassigning, without deleting

PS: Of course, assuming that the references are not kept somewhere else in your code